# Permission denied when executing script after adding path to /.bashrc

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04

I have a python script in /home/usr/.folder/scripts/ called scratch.py. I added this to /bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/usr/.folder/scripts
```

I restarted my terminal and typed:

```
scratch.py
```

and got the error:

```
bash: /home/usr/.folder/scripts/scratch.py: Permission denied
```

I also tried it with sudo and it said that scratch.py was not a recognized sudo command. I tried making the folder not hidden by removing the period in front and got the same error. What am I missing? I followed the instructions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-from-anywhere-in-linux/) to set this up.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file? That is, what does `ls -l /home/usr/.folder/scripts/scratch.py` report? Also, what is the file's shebang (first line, starting with `#!`), and what're the permissions on whatever it references?

Comment: `ls -l /home/usr/.folder/scripts/scratch.py` returns:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 39 Feb 10 17:46 /home/user/.folder/scripts/scratch.py`

         The shebang is exactly: `#! usr/bin/python3`

           The permissions for `/usr/bin/python3` are:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Feb  3 12:00 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8

Comment: I just changed the permissions of the file to executable using chmod and I no longer get the permission error but now I get: `bash: /home/user/.folder/scripts/scratch.py: usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: If this message is directly copied from your system, it is missing a `/`.  It should be `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!